# Why do I have render problems happening frequently in my Unity scene?

Tags: unity

I am making vertical endless runner. My platforms are moving down, and the camera and players are remaining in the same location, resulting in the effect of player movement. The obstacles are generated and move in same direction as platforms.

The problem is obstacles rendered by the camera is not right. I mean that the obstacles are in camera's FOV but are still visible after some time when they reach the player to close.

Comment: perhaps a screenshot of the problem would help us understand what is happening.

Comment: A gif would be more useful in this case though, since it's a problem that has movement involved. https://screentogif.codeplex.com

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure I am understanding your question. But if it is what I think it is, then you should make it so when the item hits the bottom/leaves the field of view it self destructs. If this is not the answer you are looking for then you should consider rewording your question or posting a screen shot.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/610537/best-practice-for-destroying-objects-that-are-out-1.html

Comment: Keep in mind that its very beneficial to simply pool and reuse those items rather than to create a constant stream of short lived objects.